# Find duplicates of pairwise comparisons in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, dataframe, duplicates

I have a really large data set that looks like this:

```
x1 x2
2  5
4  10
5  2
....
```

I want to find all the rows that have the same values (duplicates), however, regardless of the order. In the example above, I would like to find row 1 and 3, since they both have values 2 and 5.

Since I have approximately 14000 comparisons, how can I do this in an efficient way using MATLAB?

Comment: What would be the output for `[2 5; 4 10; 5 2; 6 7; 6 7]`?

Comment: @LuisMendo somehow a matrix , where each row has the index of the rows that contain duplicate values. So in this example maybe `[1 3; 4 5]`

Comment: @lala_12 That would fail for `[2 5; 4 10; 5 2; 6 7; 6 7; 6 7]` since you'd want the output `[1 3; 4 5 6]` which is not a valid matrix. Giving us a definition of "maybe" what you want isn't a well defined question, please decide on your preferred specific output format. A cell array of something like `{{2,5}, {1,3}; {6,7}, {4,5,6}}` would work but is not elegant.

Comment: @Wolfie The problem would be solved if you had `[1 3 0; 4 5 6]`. However, I did not think of making a cell array as you proposed. I would prefer that output.

Comment: It can be done with `sort(...,2)`, `unique` and `accumarray`. I don’t have the time (nor the computer) now; I’ll try to do it later in the day

Comment: (If someone else wants to, of course go ahead!)

Comment: @LuisMendo I was writing an answer along the same lines before I had to go off for something else! I'm sure your solution would be more elegant, but it's not clear what exact output the OP wants so I kept things simple.

Comment: @Wolfie It was the same idea as yours and then `accumarray` to collect the results as a cell array of vectors (not sure if that’s the desired output format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, sort column-wise. This means every row will have the lowest value first, and you are comparing rows regardless of the original order.

```
arr = [2 5; 4 10; 5 2; 6 7; 6 7; 6 7];
arrSorted = sort( arr, 2 );
```

Then use `unique` to get all unique rows, with their corresponding indices.

```
[uRows, ~, iRows] = unique( arrSorted, 'rows' );
```

Output:

```
>> uRows = [2  5 
            4 10
            6  7]
>> iRows = [1
            2
            1
            3 
            3
            3]
```

The array `iRows` is the index within `uRows` of each row in `arr`, so for instance the 3rd row `[6 7]` appears in the last 3 rows of `arr` (in some order).

There are a variety of formats you may want the result in. If you need more than just the arrays above, you might consider cell arrays. A simple loop would be a clear way to create this:

```
c = cell(size(uRows,1), 2);
for ii = 1:size(uRows,1)
    c{ii,1} = uRows(ii,:);         % This row
    c{ii,2} = find( iRows == ii ); % Indices of this row value within 'arr'
end
```